# Complex aggregation methods as single param in query string

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I’m trying to design a flexible API with django REST. What I meant by this is to have basically any field filterable through a query string and in addition to that have a param in the query string that can denote some complex method to perform. Ok, here are the details:

**views.py**

```
class StarsModelList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = StarsModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StarsModelSerializer
    filter_class = StarsModelFilter
```

**serializers.py**

```
class StarsModelSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**mixins.py**

```
class DynamicFieldsMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DynamicFieldsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields = self.context['request'].query_params.get('fields')
        if fields:
            fields = fields.split(',')
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

**filters.py**

```
class CSVFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        return super(CSVFilter, self).filter(qs, django_filters.fields.Lookup(value.split(u","), "in"))


class StarsModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = CSVFilter(name='id')

    class Meta:
        model = StarsModel
        fields = ['id',]
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r’^/stars/$’, StarsModelList.as_view())
```

this give me the ability to construct query strings like so:

```
/api/stars/?id=1,2,3&fields=type,age,magnetic_field,mass
```

this is great I like this functionality, but there are also many custom aggregation/transformation methods that need to be applied to this data. What I would like to do is have an agg= param like so:

```
/api/stars/?id=1,2,3&fields=type,age,magnetic_field,mass,&agg=complex_method
```

or just:

```
/api/stars/?agg=complex_method
```

where defining the complex_method grabs the correct fields for the job.

I’m not exactly sure where to start and where to add the complex methods so I would really appreciate some guidance. I should also note the api is only for private use supporting a django application, its not exposed to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely would be good to see your MyModelList class but anyway my example as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class StarsModelList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = StarsModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StarsModelSerializer
    filter_class = StarsModelFilter

    def complex_method(request):
        # do smth to input parameters if any
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('agg', None) == 'complex_method':
           return self.complex_method(request)
        return HttpResponse('Hi, World!')
```

Comment: Is this intended to replace my current StarsModelList class?

Comment: No, this is example for the class mentioned in "url(r’^/stars/$’, MyModelList.as_view())". Feel free to use StarsModelList functionality in MyModelList class

Comment: Oops that is suppose to be "url(r’^/stars/$’, StarsModelList.as_view())"

Comment: Ok, wait a bit in that case

Comment: Ok sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122841/discussion-between-sr3z-and-moku).